# If statement inside .change function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run an if statement inside a .change function but for unknown for me reason the statement is ignored. What would be the best way to achieve this.

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var currentPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.product-price-worth .price').first().text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
    var discountedPrice = ((currentPrice / 100) * 30).toFixed(0);
    var savingPrice = (currentPrice - discountedPrice).toFixed(0);




    $('.product-options').change(function() {

      if (currentPrice > 300) {

        $('span.ratio-div2').html('<p>' + currentPrice + '</p>');


        $('span.ratio-div').html('<p>' + discountedPrice + '</p>');

        $('span.ratio-div3').html('<p>' + savingPrice + '</p>');

      } else

      {
        $('span.ratio-div2').hide();


        $('span.ratio-div').hide();

        $('span.ratio-div3').hide();


      }

    });


  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the following inside `change` function

```
 var currentPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('.product-price-worth .price').first().text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""), 10);
 var discountedPrice = ((currentPrice / 100) * 30).toFixed(0);
 var savingPrice = (currentPrice - discountedPrice).toFixed(0);
```

Comment: Why would this help ?

Comment: @TusharGupta - Does your question stand valid with updated answer?

Comment: It does work but once you select a price smaller than 300 and then select bigger it does not show.

Comment: @John - Because you have hidden the elements. You need to show them too. So, in the `if` block, update code to `$(selector').html("..").show()`